# How would you get your career started?

Tags: career, opportunity

Hello world!

I'd like us to share our opinions on the best way(s) to start working in sound design and film sound in general. This is a recurring question that I am asking it to myself just now, and I've been for a while!

How do you get started, where do you get started, who do you get started with?...

I recently graduated in Digital Media, I have done some work in two years but now I'm done being a student, there is little time for me to begin getting serious! Now, I'm a person who sees all the problems, panics, and forgets about the potential solution :( I find the only cure is to shut up and get to work :)

---

**The problem I identify** (hopefully others can relate to it): there's no postprod studios where I live. I can start working on my own, BUT I won't learn and develop as fast.

**Potential solution**: there are some music studios around, BUT (again) music is not what I'm aiming at. It's ok, I'll keep working on my own, I might find a better opportunity later...

**Discuss the solution**: music is not what I want to do, but at least I'd get to practice recording, editing, maybe mixing, and I get to network with sound people (BUT not film sound people).

This is an example of how I go about never coming with a solution... So, what are you ready to do that's not a waste of time for you?

---

I've heard/read from a lot of people who came to film sound from the field of music production, but others took off in moviemaking right away. I also know that the techniques in music and film production are similar **to a certain extent**, but what is the limit for skills to remain transferrable from a field to the other? Knowledge and culture are one thing (and one should never draw a line to limit his learning) but isn't there a breaking point beyond which it's not worth going while in the early times of your career?

Answer (score 4):

I second taking up local film projects, open-source games or game mods (if you want to get into game audio.)

If you're into game audio, join the IGDA, or at least go to your local chapter's meetings, and participate in the Global Game Jam and any game-in-a-day/weekend/week/month things that you can.

The same goes for film... find your local film-makers groups, participate in the 48 Hour Film Project and other film projects.

Networking is key, and a lot of the game/film jams will bring out everyone from the kid with nothing but a cheap camera or free software to the local pros.  I've received a few offers for paid gigs simply by showing up and showing that I was interested and capable, without submitting anything formal.  Also, everyone locally knows someone regionally, and they know someone nationally... ect.  Do a good job for a local film studio and you may end up picking up a better gig from one of their peers or mentors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same shoes as you, brother. I'm also a recent graduate scanning indeed.com, Linkedin, and craigslist across all major cities almost everyday, taking up local film projects for free (currently working on sound design for two films produced by my former classmates). It's become a challenge trying to figure out how to make google efficiently search all of craigslist for the job I want. I did use a site called allofcraigs but even that site missed some jobs I found through other search techniques.